# SSAS fact modelling

Tags: ssas

Context: retail, transactions, promotions. OK, let's see some data, you will understand.

[image]

receipt_no and line_no defines a line item in a transaction (receipt_no). You can see there are two promotions applied to this item (a, b). The total discount (-3.54 - 1.19) equals to Original value - Sales (12 - 7.27). So sales (7.27) is the final value after all the promos applied.

Now I need to build this in SSAS as a fact.The business key will be receipt_no, line_no, promotion_name. The dimension related will be promotion. This is just for illustration purpose, real things are much more complicated.

So the problem will be if slice fact by promotion_name, no problem. If just see total without slicing by promotion_name, sales for this item will be doubled, which is not correct.

So how do you normally/best practice in this scenario?

Comment: If you put lines in factTable you must put and the values of lines `Sales = OriginalValue(of each promotion) - discountlines`

Comment: @Justin, the problem is our system only has original value before any promotions applied and sales after all promotions applied. There is no intermediate values.

Comment: So you must then Aggregiate all data by level which you want (if there are two same products, promotions in one receipt). Then divide SumValues(OriginalValue) by line count. So for your example you get `OriginalValue` column for each line 6 then `Sales` column `6-3.54 = 2.46` AND `6-1.19=4.81`

Comment: Hm again, if there just several promotions, probably is better that you transfer promotions from rows to columns... and in this example you just get one line with two discounts: `'DisountA' - 3.54` and `'DisountB' - 1.19`. If you can put all sample data of FactTable maybe could give better solution... Because I think there should be sales Facts and in sales facts you insert Discounts or promotions, but maybe you just creating DiscountsFacts...

Comment: @Justin There is only one line item (line no 4), the Original value 12 is before all promotions. There is no way to calculate for each promotion because there is no way to tell which promotion is applied first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see, a clean model would be to have two fact tables:

- `fact_sales` having the combination of `receipt_no` and `line_no` as the primary key, and Sales, Units, and OriginalValue as measures,
- and `fact_promotion` which would have `receipt_no`, `line_no`, and `promotion_name` as the primary key, and discount as the measure.

You could potentially omit one of Sales and OriginalValue, as each of these can be calculated from the other and the aggregated discount for the same `receipt_no` and `line_no`. But this is already starting to discuss optimization.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I thought originally. This will work if users want to see one promotion and related sales. What if users want to see sales with all related promotions? This will end up with the result set in my question. I haven't built this in SSAS, just T-SQL in underlying SQL Server database. So if I do have these two facts. How to do it to present a correct result set?

Comment: If users do not select anything from the promotions dimension, but the `discount` measure, then all other dimensions where there are selections will be taken into account, which just should deliver what you want.

Comment: @FrankPI yes, It's correct if using only discount measure. What I meant was if I want to see sales and discount measure together in one report. It will be something like one line of sales with two lines of promotions (a tree structure). I know this is probably out of scope.

Comment: @thotwielder If you want to see different rows for the discount, then you will need an attribute that separates them. Analysis Services always aggregates data to the level of the displayed attributes. The attribute to split by could either be something like discount name, or if you add that as attribute as well, the discount value. But in any case, you will only see different rows for different values of the attribute.